# Getting error in AWS SSO when trying to log in via my php application

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, single-sign-on, simplesamlphp

I was configuring aws sso with my php application, and for the application i had used simplesamlphp library https://simplesamlphp.org/docs/stable/simplesamlphp-idp#section_1. i followed the documentation and when i m accessing the application from Aws sso dashboard it works perfectly fine.
I have also done certificate configuration in my application.
But when i m trying to login from my php application at that time i m getting the error.
Plz let me know if anyone knows the solution.
Sometimes i get 403 error also.

[image]

Comment: I'm also facing same issue. Any solutions ?